# How to setup a constraint to a tvOS focused element

Tags: autolayout, tvos, focus-engine

I have a `UICollectionView` in my tvOS app that has a image and a caption text. I've setup a constraint to pin the caption text just under the image.

[image]

When the cell is focused and the images grows, the text does not move and stays over the image. Is there a way to set a constraint that takes in account the focused image size?

[image: Image without focus]

[image: Image with focus]

Comment: I am not understand what you say. You want focus move to image, at that time the label come bottom of image or over the image.

Comment: I want to specify the a vertical spacing between the label and the image when it is focused. Currently I'm able to specify this spacing only when the image is not focused

Comment: You can set the label frame on focus.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a `UIImageView` property `focusedFrameGuide` for that. It returns a `UILayoutGuide` object, which unfortunately can't be used in Interface Builder, but you can create constraints with it in code. Note that this constraint makes sense only when the view is focused, so you have to set its `active` property according to the `self.focused` property.

First create the constraint on view initialization:

```
self.focusedSpacingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView.focusedFrameGuide, attribute: .BottomMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: label, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
//add it to the view and set active to false
```

Then activate either this constraint or the default one depending on the focus:

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
  self.focusedSpacingConstraint.active = self.focused
  self.spacingConstraint.active = !self.focused

  //set label's transform and animate layout changes
}
```

You can also use the `focusedFrameGuide` to set label's height (as a percentage of image's height).

The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to change the (hardcoded) `constant` whenever the image size changes.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up setting a `@IBOutlet` to my spacing constraint and I update it in the `didUpdateFocusInContext` method. To add some effect, I also transform the label.

In my collection cell:

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
        if self.focused {
            self.spacingConstraint.constant = 30
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
                self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.15, 1.15)
                self.layoutIfNeeded()

            }
        }
        else {
            self.spacingConstraint.constant = 0
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
                self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
                self.layoutIfNeeded()

            }
        }
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, I hope it help you. This code write into the custom cell class.

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
if (self.focused) {
   self.custom_ImageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
   self.custom_LabelView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 279, 548, 29)
}
else {
   self.custom_ImageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = false
   self.custom_LabelView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 259, 548, 29)
}
}
```